# jQueryUI Slide Effect - Divs Stacking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the jQueryUI slide effect to slide one div out and another in (from left-right, right-left) using the following code:

```
$("#previous").on('click', function(){
    $("#2DivT").effect( "slide", { "direction" : "left",  "mode" : "hide"}, 900);
    $("#1DivT").effect( "slide", { "direction" : "right",  "mode" : "show"}, 900);
});

$("#next").on('click', function(){
    $("#1DivT").effect( "slide", { "direction" : "right",  "mode" : "hide"}, 900);
    $("#2DivT").effect( "slide", { "direction" : "left",  "mode" : "show"}, 900);
});
```

I am getting the slide effect that I want but my divs are stacking on top of each other, rather than sliding simultaneously side by side. I've set up a jsfiddle to display the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/aoverton07/f6rtrst3/4/

What do I need to change to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do any two animations simultaneously, you have to use the "queue" option on both effects, setting the value to false. By default, each effect is queued synchronously. Setting "queue" to false will make them run asynchronously.

In my first fiddle below, two divs slide out going left / right based on the button click. You'll notice I did some extra css manipulation to position the divs relatively on top of one another to achieve the desired sliding effect, and I have set specific widths on the elements. When doing the slide effect, extra room is required for the animated element to "go to" when showing or hiding it, thus the width and position manipulations to overcome this. Using "queue", the javascript looks like this:

```
$("#previous").on('click', function(){
    $("#2DivT").css("left", "-179px").effect("slide", { direction: "left", duration: 900, mode: "hide", queue: false });
    $("#1DivT").effect("slide", { direction: "right", duration: 900, mode: "show", queue: false });
});

$("#next").on('click', function(){
    $("#2DivT").effect("slide", { direction: "left", duration: 900, mode: "show", queue: false }, function() { $(this).css("left", "0"); });
    $("#1DivT").effect("slide", { direction: "right", duration: 900, mode: "hide", queue: false });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f6rtrst3/34/

In my second fiddle below, I have maintained your structuring as close as possible but defaulted the animation effect to "swing". This shows two animations running simultaneously and also on top of one another. Using the default "swing" animation, the javascript looks like this:

```
$("#previous").on('click', function(){
    $("#2DivT").hide({ queue : false, duration : 900 });
    $("#1DivT").show({ queue : false, duration : 900} );
});

$("#next").on('click', function(){
    $("#1DivT").hide({ queue : false, duration : 900 });
    $("#2DivT").show({ queue : false, duration : 900 });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f6rtrst3/36/

Hopefully some combination of these two fiddles will get you where you're going.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was unaware of the `queue` option.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by sliding "simultaneously" but I setup a jsfiddle that gets the gist of what I think you are going for: https://jsfiddle.net/2xm4smbL/

*You need to change the css to make it not flicker but I have no idea what you want it to look like so I haven't done it for you. You also may want to change the left and right values*

```
<table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div style="float:left;width:70%;" id="1DivT">
                  <input type="number"  />
                </div>
              </td>

              <td>
                <div style="float:left;width:70%;display:none;" id="2DivT">
                  <input type="number" />
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Basically you need to contain the contents of each `<td>` with a `<div>` to get a table to display multiple things side by side. You had them in two different tables and thus was causing the *stacking.* Once again it is very unclear what you want, but I hope I was able to help.

Comment: by simultaneous I mean one div slides out to the left, at the same time another div is sliding in from the right...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2xm4smbL/1/ So this should be what you are looking for then right? Change the background settings to prevent the bar from showing up but I left it in in order to demonstrate what is going on.

Comment: this is basically what I was looking for, except for you broke out the content from two separate `div`'s to two `td`'s, completely different structure. I can't put everything inside a table row like that, that's the dilemma

Comment: Then put the two divs that contain the two tables next to each other with a width of 50% each.

But I'd really recommended trying to fit it into the same row, as that is the simplest solution.